# Merging launchpad + stackexchange

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, launchpad, duplicate-accounts

I know it's been asked for a lot of times. But here it goes again: Please, merge my askubuntu/launchpad account with the stackexchange account. I began using launchpad back in 2010, but now I'd prefer the stackexchange integration.

My question is: why weren't all askubuntu accounts automatically linked to stackexchange?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more clear? You can use multiple login methods on the same account. Do you have that set up or do you have two different accounts with two different login methods?

Comment: I would not like my LP account automatically associated with anywhere but LP;)

Comment: Impossible to achieve what you want - LP and SE are completely separate entities run by completely separate companies.  The best you can do is ass your launchpad openid to the openid auth here, but you can't merge the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you with the question on why weren't all askubuntu accounts automatically linked to stackexchange, it is because, back when askubuntu was born, the stackexchange worked on common account systems (google, facebook)  and their own stackexchange system. The launchpad for what I remember (Anyone please correct me if am wrong) was added later, but both systems have their own, independent login systems that probably would need some work done in order to work together.

Would be good to know more about this and I find your question very good.

Answer (score 2):

As Seth said you can use multiple login methods on StackExchange, one of them is OpenID and for example the link to your Launchpad profile. Launchpad and StackExchange however are completely independent and owned by different entities, they are not different products from one company where an employee can merge your accounts.